# How to trigger an uncaught exception in React, for Sentry testing?

Tags: reactjs, sentry

I need to trigger an error in a React app to make sure that my Sentry.io has been configured correctly.

Here is what the Sentry docs is asking me to do:

```
You can trigger your first event from your development 
environment by raising an exception somewhere within 
your application. An example of this would be rendering 
a button whose onClick handler attempts to invoke a method 
that does not exist:

return <button onClick={methodDoesNotExist}>Break the world</button>;
```

However, even if I disable eslint for the file, React itself will not let me define an element whose `onClick` is an `undefined` method.

How else can I generate such an error?

Comment: Can't you just `throw 'Oh no an error'` somewhere?

Comment: Thank you this worked perfectly, I should have thought of it haha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add:

```
<button onClick={()=>{
throw 'oh no an error'`
}}> Err </button>
```

Thanks to @omnikron